# soapUI vs rest-assured for REST API testing

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rest, integration-testing, soapui

What's better for testing a REST API in built in Spring 3.1, [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) or [rest-assured](http://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/)?  oAuth 2.0 is used for authentication.

Comment: Is rest-assured able to test oauth 2.0 REST ws ? It seems it is only able to test for oauth 1.0a ones.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646402/is-there-an-advantage-in-using-soap-ui-over-rest-assured-to-automate-rest-servic has got detailed answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on who is going to create and maintain the tests. If it is going to be the QA then soapUI is the right tool. If it is going to be the developers then rest-assured.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use other tools for [REST API Testing](http://www.restcase.com) like RestCase, [Runscope](http://www.runscope.com) or [vRest](http://vrest.io/).
There are also many rest clients available like Postman and etc..