# Is there an advantage in using SOAP UI over REST-assured to automate REST Services for CI

Tags: java, web-services, jenkins, soapui, rest-assured

I have to automate REST API testing in my project and integrate it in to existing CI in jenkins.

I am about to start coding using REST-assured.However I happened to see SOAP UI REST tutorial and understand that there is a maven plugin in SOAP UI to help jenkins integration. Before I progress, just wanted to know if there is an obvious advantage to using SOAP UI over Rest-assured.
 I have to complete the automation of around 30 requests with complex JSON responses in about a month - including schema validation for responses.

Comment: Questions seeking advises may get closed.

Comment: Why the negative vote ? It is a specific question on specific technology Rao. Would much appreciate if you could give an answer rather than a simple glance and down vote.

Comment: sorry, i am not the one.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question, am sure many across globe will have same query in their mind and nothing wrong in asking merits & demerits of the each of the tools

Comment: https://techbeacon.com/5-top-open-source-api-testing-tools-how-choose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used `REST-assured`, but I had a quick look and I see it's a java `DSL` for testing rest services. Given that it does what it says it does, here's my answer...

I've used SOAP UI for testing of web services. Generally, SOAP UI has been very good for *manual* testing, but I found it difficult for *automated* testing.

The main reason was that many of the file paths are hard corded into SOAP UI projects, and so a project referring to `c:\development\myproject\wsdl\myservice.wsdl` would suddenly not work on another developer machine at `/dev/myproject/wsdl/myservice.wsdl`.

I also found not being able to effectively edit the SOAP UI projects in intellij meant I was constantly alt-tabbing.

Yes, the soap ui maven plugin did work, but I found it cumbersome.

Note that I haven't used SOAP UI REST, just "normal" SOAP UI, but if your use case is purely to implement automated testing, and that the `REST-assured` framework does what it says, I would certainly recommend to use the `DSL`.

Comment: Sorry, but disagree with your comment - `SOAP UI has been very good for manual testing, but I found it difficult for automated testing`. Because lot of people are using for automated testing including Data driven, Continuous Integration and maven plugin etc., But when we say automation, user should be aware of script to achieve more complex cases. Even you are suggesting to write in java which is again involves programming.

Comment: SOAP UI is good at automated testing via it's own interface, but terrible at automated testing *via java*. SInce the OP is using jenkins / ci, they are executing the tests via java and maven.

Comment: If you are talking about execution? It can be executed using CLI utility SOAPUI_HOME/bin/testrunner (which is based on java) and It can be invoked from jenkins as well.

Comment: @vikingsteve Please clarify what is "OP" means in your last comment "...the OP is using jenkins / ci, ..."

Comment: @vikramvi OP = original poster (QVSJ)

Answer (score 2):

Given your current use case, the simplest among the 2 would be to use rest assured (+points to java dsl; bonus readability for testing; but you can always use other clients if you want to). Given that you intend to automate your test and integrate it on CI, you can simply create a module which runs your test suite on a given phase and gather the results.

PS: i currently use jbehave + rest-assured